# Can this drain pipe be moved back closer to the exterior wall

Tags: plumbing

The attached picture might show better, but I want to get as much room as I can and based on the current rough ins, it looks like the pipe comes out at an angle from the wall. Does it make sense to dig up the concrete and make a more vertical path?

I'd like the framing to be more straight.

[image]

Here's the proposed layout (the left layout, ignore the other two). Basically I want a stand up shower on the left, toilet in the middle, and sink on the right. The drain going into the ground for the sink is what's throwing me off.

[image]

[image]

Added a new picture of wider angle. [image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Perhaps there is something under the slab, is that why the pipe deviates.

Comment: I wonder if the drain line from above (though it could be just a vent stack) is routed into the living space due to a perimeter under-slab drainage tile that needed space next to the foundation?  So the plumbing had to be brought inside of that, underneath the floor.  Though it hurts my eyes to see that vent/drain pipe from above not vertical.  At least it's inside the insulation, so it *hopefully* will never freeze.

Answer (score 1):

With the wider perspective and builder's drawing it is looking like your original assumptions are correct--the vent was intended to be in a wall parallel to the foundation. This is unfortunate, since moving it outward would require that the toilet stub also be moved. It needs to be centered 12" from the finished wall behind it. The tub drain is also in the wrong spot if you're putting in a full 60" tub.

So yes, if you wish to maximize room size, you'll need to open the floor. Unless there's some weird surprise under the slab, like an oversized footing, this shouldn't be a problem.

I'm not sure it's worth the effort, though. You probably want your wall in front of the upper horizontal run of pipe so you don't have to deal with working around that. This means you're ~4" from the vent at the floor anyway. It looks like your basement is wide open otherwise, so that 4" in a bathroom probably isn't consequential.

Comment: Thanks very much @isherwood for the detailed reply.  My apologies for not being as clear in my original question.

I added a new picture (last one lol) measuring from the base of the exterior wall to the vent pipe and toilet stub.  If the finished wall is in front of the vent pipe, taking into account 0.5 inch for drywall, then it looks like there should be enough room for the toilet.  However I'll ponder this more and will decide my next course of action.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I said the _horizontal_ section, meaning what's just under the floor joists above. It's difficult to build and secure a wall under such a pipe. Measure back 12-1/2" (or slightly more) from the center of the toilet stub. That's where your bottom plate should lie. Doesn't matter if the bottom of the vent is in the wall.